# Using a Map inside of Vuex state

Tags: dictionary, state, vuex

I'm building a prototype module to learn about **Vuex** and running into what seems like a simple issue -- I'm having trouble using a `Map` as one of my state variables.

I want to use **Vuex** to store some basic user preferences across multiple modules and figured a `Map` would be a simple way to do it since the prefs could be handled as simple key/value pairs. But I'm either not defining the `Map` correctly, or I'm not using it correctly within the mutations.

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    userSettings: Map,
  },
  mutations: {
    addUserSetting(state, payload) {
      if (state.userSettings == null) {
        state.userSettings = new Map();
      }
      state.userSettings.set(payload.key, payload.value);
    }

  },

})


</script>
```

I'd be willing to use another object, and I started with an array of `UserPref` objects but that didn't go well, either.

Comment: I don't believe Vue 2 has any support for reactivity with `Map` or `Set`. That doesn't mean they can't be used but they won't respond to changes. You haven't given enough detail about the nature of the problem you're having to know if this is relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question to include the specific error message.

Comment: Oh, I see, it's a TypeScript error, not a Vue error. I don't know any TypeScript but a bit of Googling makes me think you might need to change `userSettings: Map` to something else, possibly `userSettings: new Map()`. Currently you're assigning the `Map` constructor function as the initial value of `userSettings`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vue 2 doesn't have proper support for `Map`.

Assuming your keys are strings I suggest using an Object instead. To get a totally empty object (with no inherited properties, not even `toString`) you can use `Object.create(null)`, or just use a normal object using `{}` if that seems unnecessary.

e.g.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    userSettings: Object.create(null),
  },
  mutations: {
    addUserSetting(state, payload) {
      Vue.set(state.userSettings, payload.key, payload.value);
    }
  }
})
```

`Vue.set` must be used as the properties are being added.

Comment: This definitely fixes the error, but how would I use this to work with a collection of objects? My original goal of using Map was to have a searchable or filterable collection of user preferences. How would I add extra prefs or retrieve them later?

Comment: @KrisKramer I don't understand what you're asking. An object allows for key/value pairs just the same as the `Map` used in the question. I'm unclear why using an object prevents you from filtering, searching, adding or retrieving values.